# Random session Timeout

Tags: jakarta-ee, cookies, spring-security, session-timeout, zk

We have been using ZK framework. The session timeout set in web.xml is 60 minutes and in zk.xml it is set to default 0. That is (according to my knowledge) it will use the timeout configured in web.xml. The issue that we face these days is that session of the user expires randomly. The browser shows the message - Your session has expired. On clicking on OK, it redirects to login page which is configured in  in zk.xml. Many times the session doesn't get killed on server but the browser shows that session has expired and even it does not redirect to login page. Also the popup of session expiration keeps on coming.

So these are the two scenarios in which the user faces random session timeout:
1) When session is destroyed on server
2) Session is not destroyed on server and page is not redirected to login page.

We are using spring security 3. There is no code that explicitly fires logout in our application. Also session management is handled by cookies only.

Please suggest anything that pops up in mind..

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Weblogic is the server that we are using as application server.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
<session-config>
  <timer-keep-alive>true</timer-keep-alive>
</session-config>
```

If still timeout will happen share your code like `zk.xml` or `web.xml` files so that some one can help you.

Comment: Hi Subodh, Thanks for you answer. Sorry I am late.. Was busy with other things.. I have tried this. This has not solved the issue.. I have modified the question and added ZK.XML and WEB.XML... Please suggest if anything pops up.. Thanks..